# Joining tables using the schema names in the table using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, join

Say when I write the following query:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM Schema 1.Table1 with values:
SchemaA
SchemaB
SchemaC
```

...

And for each SchemaA, B and C I have the same tables and field, e.g

```
SELECT * FROM SchemaA.TableA which returns:
FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
value1, value2, value3
```

What I was hoping to do is some kind of join so that each row in Table1 will correspond with values from the schema tables, e.g.:

```
SCHEMA_NAME, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3
SchemaA, value1, value2, value3
SchemaB, value4, value5, value6
SchemaC, value7, value8, value9
```

I thought of looping through the table with the schema names and adding the corresponding values to a temporary table. But curious to know if there's a better method of doing this? Especially, with many different schemas.

Apologies in advance for the terrible formatting of this question, I'm asking from my mobile which has very limited options.

Comment: I format your query check first one, seem weird that `1`

Comment: Is there a set number of schemas or can that vary (i.e. are there always only schemas A, B & C or are there, sometimes, also D, E...)? Have you considered a UNION ALL query?

Comment: You didnt specify database, but you need a dinamic query. In sql server you use sp_execsql https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx